# Python matrix: instead of updating an element it updates all rows

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, matrix

```
c_k_list = [[0, 0]]*(sorted_degrees[len(sorted_degrees)-1]+1)

c_k_list[entry[1]][0] = c_k_list[entry[1]][0]+1
```

where `entry[1]=1`

In the above statement, instead of adding 1 to a particular element in `c_k_list`, it adds `1` to all the rows. 
Eg:
`c_k_list` is

```
[[1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0]]
```

instead of

```
[[0,0], [1,0], [0,0]......[0,0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Lists are objects, and so are stored by reference. Using * will just create copies of that reference. To correct this try:

```
c_k_list = [[0, 0] for i in range(5)] 
c_k_list[1][0] = c_k_list[1][0]+1
```